# Why is my SQL statement throwing a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to create a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
metalId varchar(255),
colorId varchar(255)
)
```

but it get an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AUTOINCREMENT, metalId varchar(255), colorId varchar(255) )' at
>   line 3

Anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6):

You missed an underscore. `AUTOINCREMENT` should be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

- [Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
metalId varchar(255),
colorId varchar(255)
)
```

[Here is main source.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

> Syntax for MySQL
>
> The following SQL statement defines the "P_Id" column to be an
>   auto-increment primary key field in the "Persons" table:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

> MySQL uses the AUTO_INCREMENT keyword to perform an auto-increment
>   feature.
>
> By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will
>   increment by 1 for each new record.
>
> To let the AUTO_INCREMENT sequence start with another value, use the
>   following SQL statement: ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=100